# How to fix the cellclickable in angular using gridster2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-gridster2

VERSION: ^9.3.3

***HTML***

```html
    <button (click)="toggleEditing()">{ editing ? 'cancel' : 'editing' }</button>
        <button>ADD</button>
        <gridster [options]="options">
            <gridster-item class="px-3 py-2" [item]="item" *ngFor="let item of dashboard">
         </gridster-item>
        </gridster>
```

***TS***

```js
    editing = false;
    
    ngOnInit() {
     this.options = {
          gridType: GridType.Fit,
          margin: 0,
          outerMargin: null,
          outerMarginTop: null,
          outerMarginRight: null,
          outerMarginBottom: null,
          outerMarginLeft: null,
          useTransformPositioning: true,
          mobileBreakpoint: 640,
          keepFixedHeightInMobile: false,
          keepFixedWidthInMobile: false,
          scrollSensitivity: 10,
          scrollSpeed: 20,
          enableEmptyCellClick: this.editing,
          enableEmptyCellContextMenu: false,
          enableEmptyCellDrop: false,
          enableEmptyCellDrag: this.editing,
          emptyCellDragCallback: this.emptyCellClick.bind(this),
          enableOccupiedCellDrop: false,
          ignoreMarginInRow: false,
          draggable: {
            enabled: this.editing,
            stop: (event) => { this.setFlrLayout(event); }
          },
          resizable: {
            enabled: this.editing,
            stop: (event) => { this.setFlrLayout(event); }
          },
          swap: true,
          disablePushOnDrag: false,
          disablePushOnResize: false,
          pushDirections: { north: true, east: true, south: true, west: true },
          pushResizeItems: false,
          displayGrid: DisplayGrid.Always,
          disableWindowResize: false,
          disableWarnings: false,
          scrollToNewItems: false,
          itemInitCallback: ((item: GridsterItem, itemComponent: GridsterItemComponentInterface) => {
            window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));  // to reisize respective charts 
          })
        };
    }
     toggleEditing() {
        this.editing = !this.editing;
        }


 

      ngOnChanges() {
     if (this.options && this.editing || this.options && !this.editing) {
          this.options['enableEmptyCellClick'] = this.editing;
        }
    }

     emptyCellClick(event: MouseEvent, item: GridsterItem): void {
    console.log(`test ${item}`);
    }
```

What I'm trying to do here is to multi selection grid. But the problem is the click doesn't work. when I click the empty cell it doesn't display the console in devtool.

For example i click the empty cell it should display the console or when I click a multiple select for example the first item and second item is empty then I will select the first item and second then when I click add it will add from first item and second item just like this.

[image]

TO

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your ts file, You assign the value to options, Can you replace the `enableEmptyCellClick: false` to  `enableEmptyCellClick: true`.

Thanks @ABC

Comment: I updated the code and the problem is when I click the edit it doesn't change the value edit it should be true when i click the edit

Comment: yes When you toggle the edit icon you changed only the value of `this.editing` not `this.options.enableEmptyCellClick`, `this.options. enableEmptyCellDrag` and so on.

Comment: how to make it dynamic? when I toggle/edit on it. it should change to true and when I click the cancel it should change to false.

Comment: cause If I the enableEmptyCellClick change to true then when its viewing only it can be clickable. it shouldn't click cause its viewing only.

Comment: You need to assign the dynamic options value in `toggleediting` method like `this.options.enableEmptyCellClick = this.editing`, `this.options.enableEmptyCellDrag = this.editing` and so on

Comment: ```if (this.options && this.editing || this.options && !this.editing) {
      this.options['enableEmptyCellClick'] = this.editing;
    }``` what I did is like this but the function ```emptyCellClickCallback: this.emptyCellClick.bind(this)``` for click also drag doesn't work

Comment: this function ```emptyCellDragCallback: this.emptyCellClick.bind(this)``` it doesn't work when I click the empty cell/item

Comment: You need to update this in your toggleEditing method `this.options.emptyCellDrag = this.editing`.

Note: You need to update value of `this.options` properties value whenever the changing value of `this.editing`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224075/discussion-between-abc-and-arunkumar-ramasamy).